# jQuery Variable is Not Updating with replaceWith

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to replace my DOM with a variable. But when my ajax runs it is not assigning the new value to the variable.

Any idea why the variable value isn't being replaced? I works when I write the DOM Id out as shown below but not when I replace it with a variable.

This is my code condensed that works

```
$(document).ready(){
    var url = '/Home/GetBookingsTicker';
    $('#button').on('click',function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            cache: false,
             type:"GET",
             success: function (response) {
                 $('#marqueeTop').replaceWith(response);
                 setColors($('#one').val());
             },
             failure: function () {
                 alert("Failed to update!")
             }
         });
     }
}
```

Code that doesnt work

```
$(document).ready(){
    var url = '/Home/GetBookingsTicker';
    var $one = $('#one');
    $('#button').on('click',function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            cache: false,
             type:"GET",
             success: function (response) {
                 $('#marqueeTop').replaceWith(response);
                 setColors($one.val());
             },
             failure: function () {
                 alert("Failed to update!")
             }
         });
     }
}
```

Razor

```
<div id="marqueeTop">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.one)
    <span>
        @foreach(var item in Model.procBookings){
            <label class="setTopColors">
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.GroupName)
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Sales).....
            </label>   
        }
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Does `#one` exist **before** you do the ajax request?

Comment: Or maybe it exists, but now you're holding onto a reference to an old object?

Comment: like @Danny said - is `#one` inside of `#marqueeTop`?

Comment: Where is `#one`? In the DOM before the request, or expected within the returned response?

Comment: `$('#one')` is declared before the ajax. which now that I'm saying it aloud it makes since that it would contain the old value

Comment: Like you were asked, is it inside of `#marqueeTop`?

Comment: Yes it is, adding my code now

Comment: After the ajax response, within the success callback, what does it say when you do: `alert( $('#one').length ); alert( $('#one').val() );` ?

Answer (score 0):

The second block function does not have access to variable $one. You may need to read how async AJAX requests work. To access $one you will need to implement callback in success.

Answer (score -1):

This may work if my assumption is correct about `#one`:

```
$(document).ready(){
var url = '/Home/GetBookingsTicker';

var one = $('#one').val();
$('#button').on('click',function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        cache: false,
         type:"GET",
         success: function (response) {
             $('#marqueeTop').replaceWith(response);
             setColors(one);
         },
         failure: function () {
             alert("Failed to update!")
         }
     });
 }
}
```

Comment: I didn't down vote, but this doesn't work. The value for `one` stays the same after the ajax call. So for example it starts as the value 5, my ajax runs the variable `one` remains 5. The DOM changes, but the variable does not

Comment: If you expect a new value of `#one` from the ajax response, then your second code block WILL NOT WORK as you expect. If you already assigned that variable before the ajax, then following `replaceWith`, that element will not exist again. Only the new '#one` will exist with its new value.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Thank you for taking the time to help out!